# ¿Se puede crear un arreglo de referencias a funciones?

Tags: java

En javascript por ejemplo, es posible crear un arreglo que tenga cualquier tipo de dato (incluyendo referencias a funciones y funciones en sí), ademas una variable puede contener funciones en si:

```
let misFunciones = [funcion1, miOtrafuncion, function(){}];
```

En java se que los arreglos (Los normales) solo pueden tener un tipo, en este caso si se trata de funciones, depende de si esta retorna un valor o no, (void u otro tipo).

mi pregunta es... ¿Es posible crear un arreglo de referencias a otras funciones?, y si es así, ¿Como los declaro para guardar estas referencias? (En java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Si tienes una versión de Java menores a la 8

No se puede, o al menos no se me ocurre cómo hacerlo.

### Java 8 en adelante

En Java 8 se introdujo el concepto de **Interfaz Funcional**: Una interfaz con una única función implementable que representa el tipo de la función, con su firma.

Por ejemplo, la Interfaz [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) permite expresar funciones que tengan la firma `(Tipo T) -> boolean`, por ejemplo:

```
Predicate<Integer> isEven = (number) -> number % 2 == 0;

isEven.test(2); // true
```

Esto te permite almacenar funciones como tipos, **siempre que cumplan la firma de la interfaz funcional en cuestión**:

```
// La interfaz function tiene la firma (TipoEntrada T) -> TipoSalida R
// podemos hacer un poco de magia con las wildcards para ampliar el espectro de tipos de salida

List<Function<Integer, ? extends Number>> functions = List.of(
     number -> number + 1,
     number -> number * 5d,
     Math::exp,
     Math::floor
);

functions.forEach(function -> function.apply(2));
```

Todo esto es muy tedioso porque Java, al final del día, no es un lenguaje funcional, y que las funciones no sean elementos de primer orden sino que estén supeditadas a las clases le impide trabajar con fluidez con ellas.

No sé qué pretenderás hacer con un array de funciones, pero te recomiendo que replantees tu estrategia y pienses en un modo de hacerlo que se aproxime más al modelo de POO de Java, si acaso con un leve regusto funcional.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder a esta pregunta!, he aprendido algo mas de java que no sabia, lo de hacer una array de funciones realmente no lo usaria, es solo para llegar a "contemplar" una posibilidad mas que depronto pudiese realizarse tambien en java, pero veo que simplemente no es posible, por lo pronto entonces mi duda ya esta resuelta, de verdad muchas gracias!  ;3

Answer (score 0):

Te remito a una pregunta en StackOverflow en ingles espero que te ayude :[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280727/java-creating-an-array-of-methods)

Basicamente crea una capa intermedia y luego segun que funcion quieres simplemente seleccionas el indice.

```
public class Node {
...
public void goNorth() { ... }
public void goSouth() { ... }
public void goEast() { ... }
public void goWest() { ... }

interface MoveAction {
    void move();
}

private MoveAction[] moveActions = new MoveAction[] {
    new MoveAction() { public void move() { goNorth(); } },
    new MoveAction() { public void move() { goSouth(); } },
    new MoveAction() { public void move() { goEast(); } },
    new MoveAction() { public void move() { goWest(); } },
};

public void move(int index) {
    moveActions[index].move();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Decir "funciones" en java es un poco "oscuro". ¿A qué te refieres con "funciones"? Y ¿qué, demonios, vas a hacer con estas "funciones" después?

Si quieres guardar nombres de métodos (para qué) lo puedes hacer como strings, eso es fácil ¿no? Pero en java, para ejecutar un método necesitas saber a qué clase pertenece y luego por reflexión instanciar la clase e invocar el método. En javascript puedes hacer una llamada a una función solamente sabiendo su nombre pero en java las cosas son algo más complejas. Cuando dices "guardar referencias" es más confuso todavía. Las referencias son punteros a direcciones de memoria donde se ubica el código que se va a ejecutar. Estos punteros se cargan en el registro apropiado del procesador y este ejecuta tu código. En java no puedes guardar punteros porque simplemente no los hay. Y los métodos no tienen "referencias". Así que me temo que no puedes lo que pretendes.

Y aunque en Java 8 las expresiones lambda se pueden asignar a variables, esto todavía no son referencias así que estamos en las mismas.

Echa un vistazo a [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java) y [esto](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/)

Comment: Imagino entonces que simplemente no es posible en java algo así... y con respecto a de porque no simplemente guardo un arreglo de strings con nombres de funciones, ¿Enserio es posible ejecutar una función atravez de un string?, en javascript algo así no es posible :O, (la idea es que atravez de este arreglo en determinada pocisión halla una función y yo pueda ejecutar esta función), no obtener el nombre de esta, yo que sepa en java tampoco se puede hacer esto... por eso pregunto para estar seguro jejeje.